# Setting Icon in tabLayout throws nullpointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm creating a simple project like instagram, it has 3 tabs in main activity. I want to add icons with text in tablayout tabs, but it throws exception.

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);

    tab.setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this).icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home));


    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));


}

private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String items[] = {"Home", "Upload", "Profile"};

    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new fragment3();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }
}
  }
```

This Code Throws nullpointer exception what should i do ?

**Exception Text**

> 09-29 14:33:53.004 29528-29528/com.example.eyepatch.shutter
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.eyepatch.shutter, PID: 29528
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.eyepatch.shutter/com.example.eyepatch.shutter.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
>   on a null object reference
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
>   on a null object reference
>   at
>   com.example.eyepatch.shutter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)

Comment: At line `TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);` , the `tab` seems to be null. Which means you haven't added any tabs in the `tabLayout` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You are supposed to first set the adapter to viewpager**

Re-arrange the following lines:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
tab.setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this).icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home));
viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));
```

as given below:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
tab.setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this).icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home));
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link. It helped me a lot and i think this is what you need:

> Android Material Design working with Tabs

https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).